# dolist binds argument to symbols

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

In this code dolist binds x to symbols 'foo and 'bar.

```
(dolist (x '(foo bar))
  (print (symbolp x) t))
```

This is a problem if I want to use values of foo and bar, like:

```
(dolist (x '(foo bar))
  (print x t))
```

How to get around it?

Comment: Whether the values of `foo` and `bar` are known at compile-time is totally irrelevant for `dolist`, because the `LIST` argument is not evaluated until runtime. You could, of course, write a broken macro where that is different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`x` is bound to the symbols `foo` and `bar` because `'(foo bar)` is a list containing the symbols `foo` and `bar`. If you want a list that contains the values of the variables `foo` and `bar`, you can use `(list foo bar)`.